# All purpose bbcode regex

Tags: regex

So currently, my regex:

`\*\*(.+?)\*\*`

Returns 
`***400 FAVES! Thank you so much for your love and support!**`

When I put in 
`[size=16]***400 FAVES! Thank you so much for your love and support!***[/size]`

Note that there is an additional * that is omitted at the end.

Can someone please tell me why the that is happening and what the best solution is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the normal behaviour of a non-greedy quantifier (that takes the less as possible).

You can solve the problem including optional asterisks in your capture group but this time with a greedy quantifier:

```
\*\*(.+?\**)\*\*
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/EgDDxS/1/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that your capture string contains exactly 3 stars at the beginning and end, you can use `\*{3}(.+?)\*{3}` in that case. Otherwise, a greedy expression like `\*(.+)\*` should work as long there is a star at the end and the beginning.

Output : `***400 FAVES! Thank you so much for your love and support!***`

The reason it returned 2 stars at the end in your case is non-greedy `(.+?)` part of the regex that matches as few times as possible.